# Logistic Regression - How to use model on another dataset and get probability values

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm making my first ML model and I need some help with using model on second dataset.

So I have two sets: "train_full.csv" and "test_full.csv". Both sets have the exact same structure.

Only difference is that in "train_full.csv" column "target" is filled with 0s and 1s and in "test_set.csv" this column is empty and I want to predict these values.

Below you can find my model based on "train_full.csv". I have skipped the whole part of data cleaning for clarity of code:

```py
df2 = pd.read_csv("train_full.csv", sep = ';')
test_set = pd.read_csv("test_full.csv", sep = ';')
#Dataset cleaning

#my y is column named "target", and my x's are the remaining column

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df2.drop('target',axis=1), 
           df2['target'], test_size=0.35, 
            random_state=101)

#Creating Logistic Regression Model

logmodel = LogisticRegression()
result = logmodel.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Making predictions
Predictions = logmodel.predict(X_test)

print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, Predictions))

print(metrics.classification_report(y_test,Predictions)) #Accuracy: 78%

auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_proba) #AUC: ~0.695
```

Now I want to use that model on second data set, which I have imported in the second line of code, however I dont need to split the dataset into training and testing subset anymore. I want to use model from above on the entire "test_full.csv" set. How can I do that?

Also, is there a way to add a column with calculated probability? So my output would be a pandas dataframe that would look like this:

```
Id probability target
0 0.75 1
1 0.78 1
2 0.34 0
3 0.84 1
4 0.13 0
5 0.34 0
```

Kind regards

Comment: Try something like this `Predictions2 = logmodel.predict_proba(test_set)[1]` for probability of 1.

Comment: Hey, I have tried your solution (had to remove `test_set = test_set.drop(columns = 'target')` as it contained nulls that I wanted to predict. Outcome of your line was: `array([0.8072, 0.1927])`.  I changed it a bit to: `Predictions2 = logmodel.predict(test_set)` and it returned an array of 0s and 1s. Is this how you predict binary variable - will i make a mistake if i treat this array as a "target" that I wanted to calculate?.     Outcome of proba value should be - as far as I know - one value from <0,1> for each row and based on that value "target" is calculated (1 if proba > 0.5", esle: 0)

Comment: My line should be `Predictions2 = logmodel.predict_proba(test_set)[:, 1]` - it selects column "1" previous line selected row "1". Predict_proba returns array of probabilities, for example if you have 5 classes to predict then will be 5 columns and every row will sum to 1. Threshold 0.5 is default but you can optimize its value for specific metric e.g. f1.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple.

You just need to drop the target column from the `test_set` and need to use
`logmodel.predict()` for classification and `logmodel.predict_proba()` for probability. Here is an example for the same =>

```
test_set = test_set.drop(['target'],axis=1)
```

==> below 2 lines will add a column in `test_set` dataframe which are the prob and classification related to predictions

```
test_set['prob'] = logmodel.predict_proba(test_set)
test_set['classification'] = logmodel.predict(test_set)
```